# Access XML Node

Tags: xml, powershell

I am gathering some XML from a webservice, and I receive it formatted as:

```
<devices>
  <device>
    <hostname>name</hostname>
    <SerialNumber>38xkf8</SerialNumber>
    <Uptime units="seconds">603835</Uptime>
  </device>
  <device>
    <hostname>name</hostname>
    <SerialNumber>495dkf</SerialNumber>
    <Uptime units="seconds">92548</Uptime>
  </device>
</devices>
```

I can parse through the info, but when I try and access the seconds, I cannot seem to get the data I want. When I try to access the Uptime element:

```
$xml.Devices.Device.Uptime

units                      #text
-----                      -----
seconds                    603835
seconds                    92548
```

I cannot get just the #text value returned.

Edit:

The solution:

```
Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath "//Device" | %
{
  $_.Node.Uptime.InnerText
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?  Can you show the actual XML you are parsing to get this result?

Comment: The snip-it I posed is from the actual XML file.

Comment: Then where is the other seconds coming from, or is that the error?  And is the snippet you posted the *whole* XML file?

Comment: Just as an aside - `units` would be referred to as an _attribute_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use Select-Xml to do it:

```
Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath "//Uptime" | ForEach{$_.Node.InnerText}
```

Or more simply (may not work in older versions of PowerShell, I'm not sure):

```
(Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath "//Uptime").Node.InnerText
```

Answer (score 1):

Well formed XML needs equals sign before quotation marks

```
<Uptime units="seconds">603835</Uptime>
```

Comment: That was my fault in writing the question. The actual file does have '='.